# Obtaining IP from command 'host' executed inside python

Tags: python, arrays, linux, host

I have this function to show me the 1st ip of a domain:

```
def get_ip_address(url):
    command="host "+url
    process=os.popen(command)
    results=str(process.read()) 
    marker=results.find('has address')+12   
    print results[marker:].splitlines()[0]
    return results[marker:].splitlines()[0]
```

But this only shows me the first ip. I'd like to show only the ip's. The marker is for not having "has address" as shown below (imagine I input "reddit.com":

```
['151.101.65.140', 'reddit.com has address 151.101.129.140', 'reddit.com has address 151.101.193.140', 'reddit.com has address 151.101.1.140', 'reddit.com mail is handled by 1 aspmx.l.google.com.', 'reddit.com mail is handled by 10 aspmx2.googlemail.com.', 'reddit.com mail is handled by 10 aspmx3.googlemail.com.', 'reddit.com mail is handled by 5 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.', 'reddit.com mail is handled by 5 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.']
```

I want to show only the ips, not `reddit.com has address`nor once the ip's end, `mail is handled`etc.

I tried with

```
def get_ip_address(url):
    command="host "+url
    process=os.popen(command)
    results=str(process.read()) 
    marker=results.find('has address')+12
    i=0
    arrayIps=[]
    while "has address" in results[marker:].splitlines()[i]:

        print results[marker:].splitlines()[i]
        arrayIps.append(results[marker:].splitlines()[i])
        print("array")
        print arrayIps[i]
        i=i+1
    return arrayIps
```

But it is not working! Not even returning anything useful!

What I am expecting is an array with (in this case):

```
'151.101.65.140', '151.101.129.140', '151.101.193.140', '151.101.1.140'
```

Comment: If you want to perform dns lookups in Python, why not using something like the [socket.getaddrinfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.getaddrinfo) function in the Python standard library?

Comment: Wouldn't what you are suggesting, only show the first one (as I did?). I want to show all the ones that are possible! And I used this as I wanted to call the command. @larsks

Comment: @LouisStorming It will show all the ones possible, just try it

Comment: Rather than asking what it returns, just try it out.  It will require less typing than was required to write that comment :).

Comment: it does not. I tried... @AlbinPaul

Comment: `os.popen()` has documentation which clearly says **do not use.** You might want to review https://stackoverflow.com/a/51950538/874188

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See it shows multiple hosts as you required .Your output can be generated using a `map` function

```
In [132]: socket.getaddrinfo("reddit.com", 80, proto=socket.IPPROTO_TCP)
Out[132]: 
[(<AddressFamily.AF_INET: 2>,
  <SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM: 1>,
  6,
  '',
  ('151.101.65.140', 80)),
 (<AddressFamily.AF_INET: 2>,
  <SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM: 1>,
  6,
  '',
  ('151.101.1.140', 80)),
 (<AddressFamily.AF_INET: 2>,
  <SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM: 1>,
  6,
  '',
  ('151.101.129.140', 80)),
 (<AddressFamily.AF_INET: 2>,
  <SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM: 1>,
  6,
  '',
  ('151.101.193.140', 80))]


In [134]: list(map(lambda x:x[4][0],socket.getaddrinfo("reddit.com", 80, proto=socket.IPPROTO_TCP)))
Out[134]: ['151.101.129.140', '151.101.193.140', '151.101.65.140', '151.101.1.140']
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try the dig command instead of host and apply a proper regexp aswell:

```
from subprocess import run, PIPE

def get_answer(url):
    response = run(["dig", "+noall", "+answer", "+short","{url}".format(url=url)], stdout=PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
    return response.stdout
```

**Notes:**

- The run's parameter may vary depends on why python version you are, this is an example for python 3.5: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html
- You should adapt this code to some border cases.

**EDIT**

As mentioned in commentaries, you can rid off the regex part using +short option in dig.

Comment: You don't need the regex foolery with `dig +short`

Answer (score -1):

Try splitting the string IPs at their spaces using `.split()` and then taking the last item of it `[-1]` and then splitting the last item (which should be an IP address) at the periods `.split('.')`. Join the strings returned from that using `''.join(iterable)` where iterable are the value from `.split('.')`. Check if the joined string is a numeric value using `.isnumeric()` and if that is True, print and return the last item.

```
def get_ip_address(url):
    command="host "+url
    process=os.popen(command)
    results=str(process.read())
    marker=results.find('has address')+12
    ip_list=[]
    for ip in results[marker:].splitlines()[0]:
        if ''.join(ip.split()[-1].split('.')).isnumeric():
            ip_list.append(ip.split()[-1])
    print ip_list
    return ip_list
```

The bad news is that I can't seem to get `results=str(process.read())` to be set to anything. It currently just returns an empty string, but hopefully, you'll have more luck :D

(Edit: As said in your comments, `socket.getaddrinfo()` works with flying colours. Not sure of it on Python 2.7, but it works here in 3.7.1)

(Edit2: Here's your code in 3.7.1. Should be similar in 2.7)

```
import socket
ip_list = []
for info in socket.getaddrinfo('reddit.com', 80):
    ip_list.append(info[-1][0])
```